# using htaccess redirect url with id to url with name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want a solution to redirect http://www.myexample.com/page.php?page_id=35 to http://www.myexample.com/about-us.Please help as have been googling but all in vain.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED.** You can try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /about-us? [R,L]
```

This will check, if index.php has parameter ?page_id,
if has, will redirected

Comment: its not working.could u give me some other solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, please see my edited solution. It works, I have tested it.